# Unable to get correct file path from bridge header when project name has a space

Tags: ios, xcode, file, bridging-header

I have created a manual bridging-header using these [these instructions](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/). However, my project name has a space in it. I get the following error when compiling:

> Bridging header '/Word-Word/Word-Word-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist

Here is what I have put under the bridging-header section in the project's build settings:

```
/Word-Word/Word-Word-Bridging-Header.h
```

How can I get the correct file path? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to leave the space in there rather than adding a dash between the 2 letters.

Answer (score -1):

Is that truly the path? I would tend to think not, since it implies it is at the root directory.

Assuming you mean the Objective-C Bridging Header setting from Build Settings ... that path is *relative* to the file your .xcodeproj is located. So, for example if your structure looks like

```
Word-Word.xcodeproj
Word-Word/ (note this is a directory)
Word-Word/Word-Word-Bridging-Header.h
```

You would need the Objective-C Bridging Header to be `Word-Word/Word-Word-Bridging-Header.h`.

If your bridging header is in the same directory as your .xcodeproj, then you would need to set it to be: `Word-Word-Bridging-Header.h`

Since only you right now know your directory structure, you will need to determine the proper relative path to use.